# Change a Property with a Loop

Tags: c#

I have 10 Labels and a Object with 10 Properties.
I want to have a Loop that put on the first Label the first Property of the object, on the second Label the second Property from the object and so on..

My problem is to change the property Name of the object with the loop because it isn't a string...

```
_Label1.Fill = object .Color1;     
_Label2.Fill = object .Color2;    
_Label3.Fill = object .Color3;
```

Comment: Take a look at arrays.

Comment: Put the ten property values into an array; do the same with the labels. Then loop over the arrays in parallel and set.

Comment: It sounds to me like you should have a collection of labels and a collection of colours. Having properties of Foo1, Foo2 etc is always a bad sign.

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet 's comment. Try to use 2 collections and a loop which will set the appropriate properties to the labels.

Comment: Use reflection by hardcoded property access, see the link:
[Get property value from string using reflection in C#][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp

Comment: @neo-ray for future info in comments use `[comment](link)`

Comment: (Joke) I didn't know `System.Object` had been expanded with `static` members `Color1`, `Color2`, `Color3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this with reflection like this:

```
for(int i= 1; i<= 10; i++)
{
     Label[i-1].Fill = (Color)object.GetType().GetProperty("Color" + i.ToString()).GetValue(object, null);
}
```

I assume, that you have the labels in an array or list and that the Color Properties are of type `Color`

Comment: That worked perfect, but i had to change GetValue to ...GetValue(object, null).